# When I use while in ActionListener, it just stops

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
startbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        isRun = true;
        while(isRun)
            runProgram();

    }
});

stopbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        isRun = false;
    }
});
```

When I click the `startbtn` Button, the whole program just stopped and I can't handle anything.

What's wrong?

Comment: Add the exception stacktrace to the question, if there is no stack trace you might be calling `exit()` in `runProgram()` method.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you set the variable `isRun` to `true` the program enters in the `while` loop without exiting. This happens in the same thread the GUI is running, so it becomes irresponsive and it cannot handle any other event (as the click to *Stop* the running action by setting `isRun` to `false`).

So, the solution is to run the `while` loop task in another thread, leaving the thread where the GUI is running free to handle more events.

To run the task in another thread I recommend you to use any of the classes in the concurrent framework such as [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Going even further, if your purpose is to submit a task that may be canceled, you could even use [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Also, bear in mind to use some synchronization mechanism to guarantee both threads see the latest value assigned to `isRun`.